# Generate a Summary Table for Showing Spread of each Group in Data Frame

Tags: r, tidyverse

So here is the data:

```
Year   State   Grade   Yes   
2000   AZ      A       1
2000   AZ      A       0
2000   AZ      A       1
2000   AZ      B       1
2000   AZ      B       1
2000   CA      A       1
2000   CA      A       0
2000   CA      B       0
2000   NY      A       1
2000   NY      A       1
2001   NY      B       1
```

What I'm trying to do is create a table that shows the sum of the 1's in the Yes column as a fraction of each group. The resulting table will show a value for each group based upon year, state and grade. It will look like this:

```
Year   Grade   AZ     CA   NY
2000   A       0.667  0.5  1
2000   B       1      0    1
2001   A       0      0    0
2001   B       0      0    1
```

There is more to the data including multiple values for Year, Grade and State so the table will be much larger but essentially it will return a proportion for each Group based on these three variables.

My code so far looks like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>%
    group_by(Year, State, Grade) %>%
    summarise(x = Yes / count(Yes)) %>%
    spread(State, x)
```

Comment: `data.table::dcast(df, Year + Grade ~ State, fun = mean, fill = 0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you were close... 
The second row of code is optional, to get all combinations..
just get the `sum` of `Yes`, and divide by the number of rows per group (= `n()`).. Then spread, and if you want NA = 0, don't forget the `fill = 0` at the end.

```
df %>% 
  complete( Year, nesting( State, Grade ), fill = list( Yes = 0 ) ) %>%
  group_by( Year, State, Grade ) %>%
  summarise( x = sum( Yes ) / n() ) %>%
  spread( State, x, fill = 0 )

# # A tibble: 4 x 5
# # Groups:   Year [2]
#    Year Grade    AZ    CA    NY
#   <int> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1  2000 A     0.667   0.5     1
# 2  2000 B     1       0       0
# 3  2001 A     0       0       0
# 4  2001 B     0       0       1
```

Comment: updated answer with `complete` to match the desired output